# getting audio frequency from amr file

Tags: java-me, audio-recording

I am new in j2me developing world.
I just want to know that how to get audio frequency from the audio recording application which stores data in .amr file. 
Please help me, I tried a lot, but I am helpless.
So any idea regarding this will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

look at the site mobile-tuner.com. (im new too. in fact i know nothing about java.)
but the site says that tuner function enabled phones are s60 phones. i was trying to write guitar tuner program. since my phone is nokia 5310 express music which is s40 i gave up.

so good luck to you

note: `javax.microedition.media.control.RecordControl`

--i don't know too much but i have a hunch about that ""Record Control"" class or function is related to audio frequency function in j2me. and the frequency analysis thing is inside the "sound processing"

Answer (score 0):

im gonna ad here what i have found from the other sites that may be useful to you and me(as a newbie)

1. http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?154169-Getting-Recorded-Audio-Frequency-in-J2ME

If you want frequency of sound in Hz then it is actually not a single value but a series of values as a function of time.
You will have to calculate fourier transform of the sound samples which will give you frequency.

### Read about this on wikipedia on how to calculate fourier transform and frequency graph...

1. http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?95262-Frequency-Analysis-in-J2ME-MMAPI

this forum says something about fft(fast fourrier transform) and analysing recorded amr sound rather than processing live stream  and  provides 3 link about fft which are right underneat this line have a look at them:..